# How to replace all "values" in an XML document with "0.0" using C# (preferably LINQ)?

Tags: c#, xml, regex, replace, linq-to-xml

This is not a homework; I need this for my unit tests.

Sample input: `<rows><row><a>1234</a><b>Hello</b>...</row><row>...</rows>`.

Sample output: `<rows><row><a>0.0</a><b>0.0</b>...</row><row>...</rows>`.

You may assume that the document starts with `<rows>` and that parent node has children named `<row>`. You do not know the name of nodes `a`, `b`, etc.

For extra credit: how to make this work with an arbitrary well-formed, "free-form" XML?

I have tried this with a regex :) without luck. I could make it "non-greedy on the right", but not on the left. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** Here is what I tried:

```
    private static string ReplaceValuesWithZeroes(string gridXml)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(gridXml.StartsWith("<row>"), "Xml representation must start with '<row>'.");
        Assert.IsTrue(gridXml.EndsWith("</row>"), "Xml representation must end with '<row>'.");

        gridXml = "<deleteme>" + gridXml.Trim() + "</deleteme>"; // Fake parent.
        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(gridXml);
        var descendants = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("row");
        int rowCount = descendants.Count();
        for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < rowCount; rowNumber++)
        {
            var row = descendants.ElementAt(0);
            Assert.AreEqual<string>(row.Value /* Does not work */, String.Empty, "There should be nothing between <row> and </row>!");
            Assert.AreEqual<string>(row.Name.ToString(), "row");

            var rowChildren = row.Descendants();
            foreach (var child in rowChildren)
            {
                child.Value = "0.0"; // Does not work.
            }
        }

        // Not the most efficient but still fast enough.
        return xmlDoc.ToString().Replace("<deleteme>", String.Empty).Replace("</deleteme>", String.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want us to do the entire work for you? Surely you have some skeleton of the code where only the LINQ part is left to be filled in, don't you?

Comment: Not buying it's not homework, despite your "unit test" words. "You may assume" and "For extra credit" are not words used in typical questions. Show us what you've tried that isn't working, and ask for specific help with that portion.

Comment: @Ken, Ilya, I posted my attempt above. "For extra credit" can mean that you get +25 pts for a selected answer, and I get to learn something new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        foreach (XmlElement el in doc.SelectNodes("//*[not(*)]"))
            el.InnerText = "0.0";
        xml = doc.OuterXml;
```

or to be more selective about non-empty text nodes:

```
        foreach (XmlText el in doc.SelectNodes("//text()[.!='']"))
            el.InnerText = "0.0";
```

Comment: @marc , your score is 205k wow , its really nice to meet such great people in stackoverlflow , there are lot of nice and intelligent people on SO. every day we learn something here.

Comment: @Marc, I mean that while you were busy slacking and answering questions, some people were fixing bugs in and adding features to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Hamish - oh, right, *valued associate* #6 - well, I don't have to work 24/7... I am allowed some time to eat, watch TV etc (it is 21:10 local time)

Comment: Is there a way to modify the `XPath` query to only replace text that is not white space?

Comment: @sari - geographically? UK; logistically? a home office; company? Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(myXmlFile);

foreach (var element in xml.Descendants("row").SelectMany(r => r.Elements()))
{
    element.Value = "0.0";
}
```

Note that this general search for "Desscendants('row')" is not very efficient--but it satisfies the 'arbitrary format' requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should take look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It allows you to treat html documents as well-formed xml's, therefore you can parse it and change values.

Comment: He doesn't have HTML, his document is XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Regex.Replace method in C#. I used the below regex to replace all the XML elements values:

`[>]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[<]+`

This will basically match text starting with a `'>'{some text alphabets or number}'<'`.

I was able to use this successfully in Notepad++. You can write a small program as well using this.